# Iframe, embed youtube not working on firefox

Tags: html, css, iframe, youtube, scale

I put an iframe youtube code in div tag.

```
<div id="wrap">
<iframe width="300" height="315" 
     src="//www.youtube.com/embed/82fn4mcNGJY" 
     frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

When I use css to set scale for this div tag, Firefox does not display the video

```
#wrap{
  transform: scale(1.06667);
  transform-origin: 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

[link to demo](http://jsfiddle.net/thynk113/4jjBN/)

Comment: seems not to work regardless of CSS on Firefox http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/thCe2/show

Answer (score 0):

the reason that your are using css property

> transform: scale(1.06667);

it will work fine without this property

Comment: but i want to keep this property

Answer (score 0):

Of course it'not a response..but I have exactly the same problem.
It don't works only on youtube video (maybe an embed problem). It the src iframe attribute point to another generic website,it works fine.

The problem is only on Firefox linux. It's all right on FF for OSX.